# Pygame - why LSHIFT does not respond in key repeat mode

Tags: python, keyboard, pygame

I am making a 3D engine in Pygame. An element of the controls involve using WASD, LSHIFT and SPACE to control the XYZ coordinates of the camera. I have used `pygame.key.set_repeat(1,10)` to make the keys generate multiple `pygame.KEYDOWN` events. This works fine for each of the above keys *except* **LSHIFT**.

The behavior can be reproduced by plugging in the following code into IDLE:

```
def testKeys():
    import pygame
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100,100))
    pygame.key.set_repeat(1,100)
    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE: print 'space'
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT: print 'shift'
                elif event.key == pygame.ESCAPE: done = True
```

The behavior I get is that the SPACE key works fine (generating multiple events):

```
space
space
space
space
space
```

but the LSHIFT key just generates a single event:

```
shift
```

I am using a Windows OS. Can anyone explain why this is happening, and/or propose a solution compatible (meaning similar structure) with what I have now?

Comment: @sloth That is just what I appeared to observe, whether that actually is true or not. Since cdonts has a valid solution and explanation, I think that this question is answered, and that I will not try to solve this secondary problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like MOD keys aren't taked in account by SDL when using `pygame.key.set_repeat` (which is just a Python wrapper around `SDL_EnableKeyRepeat`).

You can use this instead to get the desired behavior:

```
def testKeys():
    import pygame
    from time import time
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100,100))
    pygame.key.set_repeat(1,100)
    ticks = 0
    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE: print 'space'
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE: done = True
        new_ticks = time()
        if new_ticks - ticks >= 0.1:
            ticks = new_ticks
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_LSHIFT]:
                print 'shift'
```

Since SDL 2 key events work slightly different there's no problem while catching multiple shift key-down events (I've just tested this). Take a look at this [Pygame implementation around SDL 2](https://github.com/renpy/pygame_sdl2).

Hope it helps.